# Pandas: conditional shift

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-analysis

There is a way to shift a dataframe column dependently on the condition on two other columns? something like:

```
df["cumulated_closed_value"] = df.groupby("user").['close_cumsum'].shiftWhile(df['close_time']>df['open_time])
```

I have figured out a way to do this but it's inefficient:

**1)Load data and create the column to shift**

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.sort_values(['user','close_time'],inplace=True)
df['close_cumsum']=df.groupby('user')['value'].cumsum()
df.sort_values(['user','open_time'],inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   user  open_time close_time  value  close_cumsum
0     1 2017-01-01 2017-03-01      5            18
1     1 2017-01-02 2017-02-01      6             6
2     1 2017-02-03 2017-02-05      7            13
3     1 2017-02-07 2017-04-01      3            21
4     1 2017-09-07 2017-09-11      1            22
5     2 2018-01-01 2018-02-01     15            15
6     2 2018-03-01 2018-04-01      3            18
```

**2) shift the column with a self-join and some filters**

Self-join (this is memory inefficient)   `df2=pd.merge(df[['user','open_time']],df[['user','close_time','close_cumsum']], on='user')`

filter for 'close_time' < 'open_time'. Then get the row with the max close_time

```
df2=df2[df2['close_time']<df2['open_time']]
idx = df2.groupby(['user','open_time'])['close_time'].transform(max) == df2['close_time']
df2=df2[idx]
```

**3)merge with the original dataset:**

```
df3=pd.merge(df[['user','open_time','close_time','value']],df2[['user','open_time','close_cumsum']],how='left')
print(df3)
```

output:

```
   user  open_time close_time  value  close_cumsum
0     1 2017-01-01 2017-03-01      5           NaN
1     1 2017-01-02 2017-02-01      6           NaN
2     1 2017-02-03 2017-02-05      7           6.0
3     1 2017-02-07 2017-04-01      3          13.0
4     1 2017-09-07 2017-09-11      1          21.0
5     2 2018-01-01 2018-02-01     15           NaN
6     2 2018-03-01 2018-04-01      3          15.0
```

**There is a more pandas way to get the same result?**

**Edit:** I have added one data line to make the case more clear.
My goal is to get the sum of all transactions closed before the opening time of the new transaction

Comment: Is anything wrong with @Wen's answer?  seems like the bounty was added after wen's answer but I don't see anything wrong with wen's answer.  Can you elaborate if you want something more or different than that?

Comment: Ok , since you change the question , I am updating my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a modification to you test case that I think you should include. This solution does handle your edit.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("cond_shift.csv")
df
```

input:

```
   user open_time   close_time  value
0   1   12/30/2016  12/31/2016  1
1   1   1/1/2017    3/1/2017    5
2   1   1/2/2017    2/1/2017    6
3   1   2/3/2017    2/5/2017    7
4   1   2/7/2017    4/1/2017    3
5   1   9/7/2017    9/11/2017   1
6   2   1/1/2018    2/1/2018    15
7   2   3/1/2018    4/1/2018    3
```

create columns to shift:

```
df["open_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["open_time"])
df["close_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["close_time"])
df.sort_values(['user','close_time'],inplace=True)
df['close_cumsum']=df.groupby('user')['value'].cumsum()
df.sort_values(['user','open_time'],inplace=True)
df


   user open_time   close_time  value   close_cumsum
0   1   2016-12-30  2016-12-31  1       1
1   1   2017-01-01  2017-03-01  5       19
2   1   2017-01-02  2017-02-01  6       7
3   1   2017-02-03  2017-02-05  7       14
4   1   2017-02-07  2017-04-01  3       22
5   1   2017-09-07  2017-09-11  1       23
6   2   2018-01-01  2018-02-01  15      15
7   2   2018-03-01  2018-04-01  3       18
```

Shift columns (explanation below):

```
df["cumulated_closed_value"] = df.groupby("user")["close_cumsum"].transform("shift")
condition = ~(df.groupby("user")['close_time'].transform("shift") < df["open_time"])
df.loc[ condition,"cumulated_closed_value" ] = None
df["cumulated_closed_value"] =df.groupby("user")["cumulated_closed_value"].fillna(method="ffill").fillna(0)
df


user    open_time   close_time  value   close_cumsum    cumulated_closed_value
0   1   2016-12-30  2016-12-31  1       1               0.0
1   1   2017-01-01  2017-03-01  5       19              1.0
2   1   2017-01-02  2017-02-01  6       7               1.0
3   1   2017-02-03  2017-02-05  7       14              7.0
4   1   2017-02-07  2017-04-01  3       22              14.0
5   1   2017-09-07  2017-09-11  1       23              22.0
6   2   2018-01-01  2018-02-01  15      15              0.0
7   2   2018-03-01  2018-04-01  3       18              15.0
```

All of this has been written is such a way that it's done across all users. I believe the logic is easier if you only focus on one user at a time.

- Assume no events happens at the same time. This is the same thing as
  shifting the cumulative sum down one row.
- Remove events that happens    at the same time as other events.
- Fill in the missing values. With a forwards fill.

I would still thoroughly test this before you use it. Time intervals are weird and there are a lot of edge cases.

Answer (score 9):

I am using a new para here record the condition `df2['close_time']<df2['open_time']`

```
df['New']=((df.open_time-df.close_time.shift()).dt.days>0).shift(-1)
s=df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x : (x['value']*x['New']).cumsum().shift()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
s.loc[~(df.New.shift()==True)]=np.nan

df['Cumsum']=s




df

Out[1043]: 
   user  open_time close_time  value    New Cumsum
0     1 2017-01-01 2017-03-01      5  False    NaN
1     1 2017-01-02 2017-02-01      6   True    NaN
2     1 2017-02-03 2017-02-05      7   True      6
3     1 2017-02-07 2017-04-01      3  False     13
4     2 2017-01-01 2017-02-01     15   True    NaN
5     2 2017-03-01 2017-04-01      3    NaN     15
```

Update : since op update the question (Data from Gabriel A)

```
df['New']=df.user.map(df.groupby('user').close_time.apply(lambda x: np.array(x)))
df['New1']=df.user.map(df.groupby('user').value.apply(lambda x: np.array(x)))
df['New2']=[[x>m for m in y] for x,y in zip(df['open_time'],df['New'])  ]
df['Yourtarget']=list(map(sum,df['New2']*df['New1'].values))
df.drop(['New','New1','New2'],1)


Out[1376]: 
   user  open_time close_time  value  Yourtarget
0     1 2016-12-30 2016-12-31      1           0
1     1 2017-01-01 2017-03-01      5           1
2     1 2017-01-02 2017-02-01      6           1
3     1 2017-02-03 2017-02-05      7           7
4     1 2017-02-07 2017-04-01      3          14
5     1 2017-09-07 2017-09-11      1          22
6     2 2018-01-01 2018-02-01     15           0
7     2 2018-03-01 2018-04-01      3          15
```

Comment: Thank you Wen. I think that your solution is great but my case it's little more sophisticated. I have added some edits to make all clear

Comment: @riccardonizzolo I believe , the back end logic should be same, just need to polish :-)

Comment: this is amazingly concise ;-)

Comment: If you add the first date from my example, you'll see your method doesn't get the right answer. It works for a conditional shift, but not for the specific situation in the edit.

Comment: @GabrielA if you check the edit history of the question you will see he update the question my answer working for the first version

Comment: It's more of a note for future people looking at this question. But yes, I understand why it doesn't match.

Comment: @GabrielA also, he is update the question after I made my question, the best way is open a new topic rather than update

Comment: @GabrielA thank you make me aware of this , I will update my answer (which I usually not do )

Comment: @GabrielA check the update , I still control it within 5 line

Answer (score 6):

(Note:  @wen's answer seems fine to me, so I'm not sure if the OP is looking for something more or something different.  In any event, here's an alternate approach using `merge_asof` that should also work well.)

First reshape the dataframes as follows:

```
lookup = ( df[['close_time','value','user']].set_index(['user','close_time'])
           .sort_index().groupby('user').cumsum().reset_index(0) )

df = df.set_index('open_time').sort_index()
```

The idea with "lookup" is simply to sort by "close_time" and then take a (grouped) cumulative sum:

```
            user  value
close_time             
2017-02-01     1      6
2017-02-05     1     13
2017-03-01     1     18
2017-04-01     1     21
2017-09-11     1     22
2018-02-01     2     15
2018-04-01     2     18
```

For "df" we just take a subset of the original dataframe:

```
            user close_time  value
open_time                         
2017-01-01     1 2017-03-01      5
2017-01-02     1 2017-02-01      6
2017-02-03     1 2017-02-05      7
2017-02-07     1 2017-04-01      3
2017-09-07     1 2017-09-11      1
2018-01-01     2 2018-02-01     15
2018-03-01     2 2018-04-01      3
```

From here, you just want to conceptually merge the two datasets on "user" and the "open_time"/"close_time" but the complicating factor is that we don't want to do an exact match on the time, but rather a sort of "nearest" match.

For these sorts merges you can use `merge_asof` which is a great tool for various non-exact matches (including 'nearest', 'backward', and 'forward').  Unfortunately due to the inclusion of groupby, it's necessary to also loop over the users, but it's still pretty simple code to read:

```
df_merged = pd.DataFrame()

for u in df['user'].unique():
    df_merged = df_merged.append( pd.merge_asof( df[df.user==u],  lookup[lookup.user==u], 
                                                 left_index=True, right_index=True, 
                                                 direction='backward' ) )

df_merged.drop('user_y',axis=1).rename({'value_y':'close_cumsum'},axis=1)
```

Results:

```
            user_x close_time  value_x  close_cumsum
open_time                                           
2017-01-01       1 2017-03-01        5           NaN
2017-01-02       1 2017-02-01        6           NaN
2017-02-03       1 2017-02-05        7           6.0
2017-02-07       1 2017-04-01        3          13.0
2017-09-07       1 2017-09-11        1          21.0
2018-01-01       2 2018-02-01       15           NaN
2018-03-01       2 2018-04-01        3          15.0
```