# How to loop or repeat code in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop, trading

I have a pandas Dataframe which I am using to backtest some trading signals and have created a column in my Dataframe which shows to position of the trade (i.e. open). See the table below:

| Date / Time | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume | Signal | Stop Loss | Take Profit | Trade Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-07-03 07:00:00 | 1.24651 | 1.24673 | 1.24596 | 1.24603 | 600 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 07:30:00 | 1.24601 | 1.24641 | 1.24568 | 1.24594 | 487 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 08:00:00 | 1.24593 | 1.24618 | 1.24580 | 1.24612 | 455 | Open | 1.18351 | 1.86927 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 08:30:00 | 1.24612 | 1.24667 | 1.24603 | 1.24666 | 552 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | Open |
| 2020-07-03 09:00:00 | 1.24666 | 1.24785 | 1.24623 | 1.24765 | 922 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 09:30:00 | 1.24765 | 1.24806 | 1.24730 | 1.24764 | 806 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 10:00:00 | 1.24763 | 1.24862 | 1.24649 | 1.24685 | 1246 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 10:30:00 | 1.24683 | 1.24690 | 1.24373 | 1.24580 | 1839 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 11:00:00 | 1.24583 | 1.24684 | 1.24538 | 1.24633 | 1001 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |
| 2020-07-03 11:30:00 | 1.24633 | 1.24705 | 1.24573 | 1.24625 | 1081 | 0 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 0 |

The code for the 'Trade Position' column is as follows:

```
GBPUSDM30_form.loc[((GBPUSDM30_form['Signal'].shift(1) == 'Open') | (GBPUSDM30_form['Trade Position'].shift(1) == 'Open'), 'Trade'] = 'Open'
```

The 'Trade Position' column should state 'Open' if the 'Signal' column or 'Trade Position' column on the row above show 'Open'.

This has been successful on one row, as we can see above (2020-07-03 08:30:00), however all of the rows underneath should also state 'Open' in the 'Trade Position' column. Please could somebody explain how to make this happen?

Comment: Do you want to make a new column with name "Trade"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Trade'] = df['Signal'].transform('shift')
condition = (df['Signal'].transform("shift") != 'Open') & (df['Signal'].transform("shift") != 'Close')
df.loc[condition,"Trade"] = None
df["Trade"] =df['Trade'].fillna(method="ffill").fillna(0)

df['Trade'].loc[df['Signal'] == 'Close'] = 'Close'
df['Trade'].loc[(df['Signal'] == 'Open') | (df['Trade Position'] == 'Open')] = 'Open'

df
```

This the output:

| Signal | Trade Position | Trade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Open | 0 | Open |
| 0 | Open | Open |
| 0 | 0 | Open |
| Close | 0 | Close |
| 0 | 0 | Close |
| 0 | 0 | Close |
| Open | 0 | Open |
| 0 | 0 | Open |

I have put a `Close` signal, and an extra `Open` Signal, after the `Close` signal, so that you can see how the `Trade` column switches from *Open* to *Close* signals.

Here is a useful answer: [Pandas: conditional shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646684/pandas-conditional-shift)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I would like the 'Trade Position' column to state 'Open' on every row underneath the signal 'Open', until I enter a close signal. Unfortunately the date frame only shows 'Open' on one row at the moment. Could you assist on this please? Thanks.

Comment: @Lou_Ellis_1998 I 've re-uploaded my answer. Update me if it works please.

Comment: @Lou_Ellis_1998 did you solve your problem?